# Botão para fazer caixa de texto desaparecer com o primeiro click, e reaparecer com um segundo

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando desenvolver um botão no Adobe Acrobat com alguma variável que o permita, com um click, fazer uma certa caixa de texto desaparecer, e com um segundo, fazer a própria reaparecer novamente. Ficando nesse vai e vem eterno. Eu tentei com o meu código em JavaScript, mas ele só faz a caixa desaparecer e não reaparecer novamente conforme eu clico novamente. Aqui o meu código:

if (this.getField("15.0 - Assinatura 1 - TAB 14").display == "display.hidden"){ this.getField("15.0 - Assinatura 1 - TAB 14").display = display.visible; } else { this.getField("15.0 - Assinatura 1 - TAB 14").display = display.hidden; }

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A dica que eu posso oferecer é separar em duas funções, onde uma chama a outra, fazendo a segunda com a parte de reaparecer após um seg.
Exemplo:

```
$("meuBotão").on("click", function(){
  "sua func"
  funcao2();
});

var funcao2 = function(){
"Sua segunda func"
};
```

Do jeito que colocou, o botão não vai saber que precisa voltar depois de um segundo. Apenas vai voltar se ele estiver como hiden.

OBS.: Eu sei que fiz com jQuery, mas é que esqueci algumas coisas de JS, e eu manjo mais de jQ

Comment: Obrigado pela a dica! Tentarei fazer isso, mesmo não sendo tão bom também com o JS.